# Wrong inverse matrix using ZGETRI in Fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran, lapack, intel-fortran

I am trying to compute the inverse of a complex matrix with ZGETRI, but
even if it executes without error (info = 0),
it does not give me the correct inverse matrix and I have absolutely
no idea where the error comes from.

```
PROGRAM solvelinear
implicit none
INTEGER                        :: i,j,info,lwork
INTEGER,dimension(3)        :: ipiv
COMPLEX(16), dimension(3,3) :: C,Cinv,M,LU
COMPLEX(16),allocatable :: work(:)

info=0
lwork=100
allocate(work(lwork))
ipiv=0
work=(0.d0,0.d0)

C(1,1)=(0.d0,-1.d0)
C(1,2)=(1.d0,5.d0)
C(1,3)=(2.d0,-2.d0)
C(2,1)=(4.d0,-1.d0)
C(2,2)=(2.d0,-3.d0)
C(2,3)=(-1.d0,2.d0)
C(3,1)=(1.d0,0.d0)
C(3,2)=(3.d0,-2.d0)
C(3,3)=(0.d0,1.d0)

write(*,*)"C = "
do i=1,3
   write(*,10)(C(i,j),j=1,3)
end do

!-- LU factorisation
LU=C
CALL ZGETRF(3,3,LU,3,ipiv,info)
write(*,*)'info = ',info
write(*,*)"LU = "
do i=1,3
   write(*,10)(LU(i,j),j=1,3)
end do

!-- Inversion of matrix C using the LU

Cinv=LU
CALL ZGETRI(3,Cinv,3,ipiv,work,lwork,info)
write(*,*)'info = ',info
write(*,*)"Cinv = "
do i=1,3
   write(*,10)(Cinv(i,j),j=1,3)
end do

!-- computation of C^-1 * C to check the inverse
M = matmul(Cinv,C)
write(*,*)"M = "
do i=1,3
   write(*,10)(M(i,j),j=1,3)
end do
          10 FORMAT(3('(',F20.10,',',F20.10,') '))

END PROGRAM solvelinear
```

I compile with `ifort` (and my `LAPACK` librairies version 3.7.1 are also compiled with ifort). Makefile:

```
#$Id: Makefile $
.SUFFIXES: .f90 .f .c .o
FC = ifort
FFLAGS = -g -check all -zmuldefs -i8
LIBS = -L/path/to/lapack-3.7.1 -llapack -ltmglib -lrefblas
MAIN = prog.o
EXEC = xx
all:  ${MAIN} Makefile
    ${FC} ${FFLAGS} -o ${EXEC} ${MAIN} ${LIBS}
.f.o: ${MODS} Makefile
    ${FC} ${FFLAGS} -c $<
.f90.o: ${MODS} Makefile
    ${FC} ${FFLAGS} -c $<
```

I have no errors when compiling. Here is my output:

```
 C = 
(       0.00000,      -1.00000) (       1.00000,       5.00000) (       2.00000,      -2.00000) 
(       4.00000,      -1.00000) (       2.00000,      -3.00000) (      -1.00000,       2.00000) 
(       1.00000,       0.00000) (       3.00000,      -2.00000) (       0.00000,       1.00000) 
 info =                      0
 LU = 
(       4.00000,       0.00000) (       2.00000,  120470.58824) (       2.00000,      -2.00000) 
(       0.00000,       0.00000) (28003147.29412,      -3.00000) (      -1.00000,       2.00000) 
(       1.00000,       0.00000) (       3.00000,      -2.00000) (       0.00000,       1.00000) 
 info =                      0
 Cinv = 
(       0.00000,       0.00000) (      -0.00000,      -0.00000) (       2.00000,      -2.00000) 
(      -0.00000,       0.00000) (      -0.00000,      -3.00000) (      -1.00000,       2.00000) 
(      -0.00000,      -0.00000) (       3.00000,      -2.00000) (       0.00000,       1.00000) 
 M = 
(       2.00000,      -2.00000) (       2.00000,     -10.00000) (       2.00000,       2.00000) 
(      -4.00000,     -10.00000) (      -8.00000,       2.00000) (       4.00000,       2.00000) 
(      10.00000,     -10.00000) (       2.00000,     -10.00000) (      -0.00000,       8.00000)
```

And M should be the identity if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Please don't put tags into the title in parentheses as you did. StackOverflow has a rich tag system, put tags below the question where they belong. If they are integral part of the title they can stay there (like the "in Fortran" or "in a Fortran function" or similar), but don't just put a list there, the list of tags is below the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to NOT use the kind notation with literal numbers like `REAL(4)` or `COMPLEX(16)`.

First, it is ugly and not portable.

Second, it can be confusing for complex variables.

Here you define your variables as `COMPLEX(16)`, but `ZGETRI`, and all other LAPACK `Z` routines, expects `COMPLEX*16`. These are **NOT** the same.

`COMPLEX*16` is a non-standard notation for complex numbers with `REAL*8` components. `REAL*8` is a nonstandard notation for 8 byte real numbers that are normally equivalent to `DOUBLE PRECISION`.

`COMPLEX(16)` is a complex number with two `REAL(16)` components, provided such a kind exists. In compilers which provide `REAL(16)` this  real is a quadruple precision, not double precision.

So you are effectively passing 32-byte complex variables instead of 16-byte complex variables.

There are enough resources where to learn how to use Fortran kinds properly. You can start with

```
integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)
```

and

```
real(dp) :: x
complex(dp) :: c
```

Comment: I'm wondering whether the "best" approach may be to use complex*16 rather than complex(kind(1.0d0)) to match the type used in the original source http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/zgetrf.f.html , but I'm not sure how it is defined in the reference (or latest or mkl or...) libraries in practice.

Comment: I mention that in the answer, but I won't recommend this way, because it is not (standard) Fortran.

Comment: @roygvib The main reason for COMPLEX*16 there is because there was no standard DOUBLE COMPLEX, but DGETRF uses DOUBLE PRECISION, so I would recommend using `kind(1.d0)`.

Comment: Thanks for your info, yes I agree that kind(1.d0) is practically the best (and I use it). My concern is that if the default real is set to 64-bit (by compiler options or something), possible trouble might happen in future... (In that sense, complex(real64) from iso_fortran_env might be safer). But before that, Lapack itself is using 1.0D0 and complex*16 (or real*8) in a mixed way, so chaotic... lol (But this is just an extremely minor concern, so I also think complex(kind(0.d0)) would be most practical.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments, it fixed my problem. So if I understood it correctly, complex(16) was wrong here because the compiler I used did not have the quadrupole precision for real(16) ? Anyway, I will use your recommendation in the future :)

Comment: @B_runo Not exactly. The compiler did have the quadruple precision, but the quadruple precision is not compatible with `Z` routines like `ZGETRF`. They require double precision.

Comment: Okay, I get it ! Thank you for those precisions.